# How to return collection of entities without pagination? Spring Boot REST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have simple Spring Boot application. My controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    return employeeRepository.findAll();
}
```

This code produce this json:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "employees" : [ {
      "firstName" : "firstName1",
      "lastName" : "lastName1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/1"
        },
        "employee" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/1"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "firstName" : "firstName 1",
      "lastName" : "lastName 1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/2"
        },
        "employee" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/2"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "firstName" : "firstName 3",
      "lastName" : "lastName 3",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/4"
        },
        "employee" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees/4"
        }
      },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employees"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/employees"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 7,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

But I need something like this:

```
[
    {
      "firstName" : "firstName1",
       "lastName" : "lastName1",
    },
        {
      "firstName" : "firstName2",
       "lastName" : "lastName2",
    },
]
```

Comment: You can use @JsonView to choose the data that youn want to show. See http://coderelief.io/index.php/2015/11/07/control-your-json-serialization-with-jackson-jsonview-and-spring-boot/

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez as I know, this Annotation is used for selecting fields of Entity. Pagination appeared out of  spring-boot-starter-data-rest. But I dont know, how to disable it.

Comment: Your employeeRepository has been defined as a PagingAndSortingRepository. If you don't need pagination define it as a simple CrudRepository. If you want to controll the pagination (max results, etc) you must use parameters in the url of the request, for example http://localhost:8080/?limit=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is removing **spring-boot-starter-data-rest** module.